# How to install TheBrain software on ubuntu/kubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, kubuntu

I am completely new to Linux based operating systems and am having trouble installing programs. I downloaded the latest version of TheBrain but can't seem to install it. I've made the file executable and it is located in my downloads folder which is in the home folder.

I've tried installing through the Konsole terminal by typing:

```
chmod +x TheBrain_unix_8_0_0_4.sh
```

And it tells me `no such directory or file exists`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you in the downloads folder while writing `chmod …`? What does `pwd` say?

Comment: Doing `ls` will tell you if you are in the same folder as the script.  It is likely you have downloaded it somewhere else.  You can use the `cd` command to get there.  Like `cd ~/Downloads` will change directory to the Downloads folder in your home directory.

Comment: I wasn't in the downloads folder but using the cd command I am now. I tried retyping the chmod command and nothing happens. No message or anything

Comment: Well, perfect. In Unix/Linux, you only get a message when something didn't work. Now that the `chmod` worked, try typing `./TheBrain_unix_8_0_0_4.sh`.

Comment: Well we are getting somewhere! (: So I typed in the command and it said "No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system. Do you want to download JRE (y/n)" I tried to download the JRE and at the end of the text it says "Could not display the GUI. This application needs access to an X Server." "You can also run this app in console mode without access to an X server by passing the argument -C"

Comment: Fixed it! The thread that really helped me was http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-ubuntu-12-04.html Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 0):

To iterate the info from the comments and turn this into a proper answer: Make sure that you are in the same directory as the file you want to modify. If you downloaded it to `~/Downloads` (the download folder in your home directory), then first `cd` there:

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod +x TheBrain_unix_8_0_0_4.sh
```

Now you can execute the file:

```
./TheBrain_unix_8_0_0_4.sh
```

As for installing Java, see [this article](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-ubuntu-12-04.html).